# What is the proper method to install a Debian package onto a device stuck on a private network?

Tags: apt, iptables, package-management, dpkg, nftables

Here is my scenario:

I want to install iptables onto an embedded Linux device that is located on a private network with no access to the internet. I can place my Windows PC onto this network and then perform SSH/FTP operations. Note, I can't move the Linux device onto a network that has internet access.

This Debian based embedded Linux device should be able to run iptables, however, I'm finding it to be a pain to install. I can FTP over .deb files for dpkg, however, I'm struggling to resolve the dependency chain.

So my constraints of the device not being able to be reach the internet and the only way I have access to the device is via SSH/FTP, what would be the best method to install iptables? Here's what I can think of:

1. Use some sort of 'apt' feature that allows you to download all of the required packages to a zipped folder. And then FTP over all of the dependencies. I don't know if such a thing exists.
2. Find some version of iptables that has all dependencies statically linked. FTP that over to the Linux device.
3. Compile the iptables from source code on the device.

Note: There is no nftables utility on this device either. I don't believe it has any sort of local firewall daemon.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
PACKAGES="iptables"; apt-get download $(apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances --no-pre-depends ${PACKAGES} | grep "^\w")
```

Please take note, that sometimes dependencies can be really large, especially for graphical programs. Answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756800/how-to-download-all-dependencies-and-packages-to-directory

PS variable PACKAGES can contain more than one package, delimited by spaces, like so:

```
PACKAGES="package1 package2 package3 package4"
```